# Django cache.set() fails on a class with a GenericForeignKey, What can be the cause?

Tags: django, memcached, picking, django-cache

I have a model with a `GenericForeignKey`. When calling `cache.set(key, trac_obj)`, it fails. I wonder if the `GenericForeignKey` is the culprit?

```
# models.py
class Trac(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="%(class)s", null=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'content_type', 'object_id'),)

# views.py
obj = SomeUserProfile # Django UserProfile (or any other model object)
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(type(obj))
trac_obj = Trac(user=request.user, content_type=content_type, object_id=obj.pk,
                                   content_object=obj)
trac_obj.save()
cache_key = 'Trac-{0}-{1}-{2}'.format(user.id, content_type.id, obj.id)
cache.set(cache_key, trac_obj)
```

Here is the error message:

```
File ".../python2.7/site-packages/memcache.py", line 751, in _val_to_store_info
pickler.dump(val)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle instancemethod objects
```

Comment: I'm sorry if this is stupid, but could you show how you create trac_obj?

Comment: Here you go Josh, I added more info

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20212

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be because one can't directly pickle the results of the `.save()` method. Try setting the cache before saving the object.

If you must pickle the `.save()`, there seem to be ways as elaborated in the answers to this OP:
http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/552476-why-cant-you-pickle-instancemethods